# How to use the GLOP Linear Solver with Visual Studio 2017 [C++]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, or-tools

I've been trying to get this to work for a while but cant figure it out for the life of me. 
Here's my situation right now:

I have a Visual Studio project (and solution) up and running, and would like to modify it as little as possible. I now feel the need to use GLOP Linear solver within my project, and was wondering how I'd go about doing this.

The code that I've written that uses GLOP works perfectly as a standalone .cpp file : 
[ this .cpp file is placed in the same directory as the resources for GLOP, and compiles and runs perfectly after creating and using the make command as mentioned here https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/cpp
]

I would now like include this code in my project, and run it as a part of my project rather than as standalone code. As I'm currently using MSVS 2017, I was wondering how I'd go about doing this as the current tricks I've used (copying and pasting all the resources for GLOP in the project folder, among other things) don't seem to be working and my error list keeps growing, and using the make commands is obviously not an option as the code needs to embedded amongst other code.

Please explain to me like I'm five years old - what files are supposed to go where, what linkages am I supposed to perform and what other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have already downloaded and extracted the binary archive:
[or-tools_VisualStudio2017-64bit_v6.8.5452.zip](https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/download/v6.8/or-tools_VisualStudio2017-64bit_v6.8.5452.zip)

When running the `make rcc` command to build a C++ example, you should have spotted the needed flags to use in your project.

First you need to configure your project to add the `include` directory:
`Configuration Properties`>>`VC++ Directories`>>`Include Directories`

[image: vs include directory]

Then you must add some preprocessor flags e.g. `-DUSE_GLOP`
note: you can find [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/tools/Makefile.cc.java.dotnet#L124) what we use in the Makefile:
`Configuration Properties`>>`C/C++`>>`Preprocessor`>>`Preprocessor Definitions`
[image: vs preprocessor]

Then add the static library `libortools.lib` to your linker:
`Configuration Properties`>>`Linker`>>`Input`
[image: linker input]

Note: Images come from various sites on the internet please adapt it.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works, but I did the same thing you did without the use of any flags. It compiles, builds and runs fine, so I was wondering if the absence of the flags would have any implications in bigger projects.

What exactly is it that the flags do?